# Kendo Grid Limit Pages Displayed before Ellipsis

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, data-paging

I am putting a kendo grid on my mobile app.  The number of pages is around 15 or 16 with a page size of 7.  Right now the grids pager shows 1 2 3 4 5 etc all the way to 10 and then the ellipsis.  I want to only see the first 5 pages and then the ellipsis...  Is there some sort of ranging I can do on a kendo grid to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing `buttonCount : 5` in `pageable` option of kendoGrid. like

```
pageable: {
    buttonCount: 5
}
```

Check Kendo Documentation here for [**pageable.buttonCount**](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-pageable.buttonCount)